# If a creature with damage transfer is grappling a target, and the grappled target hits the creature, does the target still take half the damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, damage-reduction

A particular situation brought up this issue– a slithering tracker has the damage transfer ability:

> While grappling a creature, the slithering tracker takes only half the damage dealt to it, and the creature it is grappling takes the other half.

It had my character grappled, and I hit it with an attack. The DM judged that I took half that damage because of the damage transfer ability. I argued that the damage transfer makes sense if someone *else* is hitting it, but how could I be doing damage to myself?

Answer (score 18):

### There are no exceptions to the damage transfer

The feature states

> While grappling the target, the slithering tracker takes only half **any damage** dealt to it (rounded down), and the target takes the other half.

There is no mention that this does not apply to attacks from the grappled creature, so it applies to all attacks. Even to other things than attacks - it applies to *any damage* the tracker takes, also from spells and other sources.

If you need a narrative justification for the rules behavior, think of it as the tracker coating you like a thin, wet layer. Very hard to hit, bite, or burn, without also hitting biting or burning you.

Note that

> Until this grapple ends, the target is restrained and unable to breathe unless it can breathe water.

So if the grappled creature wanted to attack the tracker, it also would do that with Disadvantage.

Comment: AKA the usual "stop ~~hitting yourself~~ cutting your own foot off with your dagger" bullying maneuver. [~~comments cannot include strikethrough~~](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63769/271150)

Comment: Is "damage transfer" an actual term used in the game? If so, something like "This attack is unaffected by damage transfer abilities" would easily be an exception.

Comment: @EgorHans It is a named trait. The Cloaker and Rug of Smothering have it, too, and the DMG monster building rules (p 280 DMG) list it. So you are right, there could be a feature or item printed that gets around it. I am however not aware of any in existence to date. The PHB has 0 hits, DMG and MM just those just discussed. Even if such an item existed, this would be a specific beats general situation, there are no general types of attacks that are exceptions to the transfer ability, and that is what the querant is asking about.

Answer (score 8):

### Your DM was right

Slithering Tracker's *Damage Transfer* says:

> While grappling a creature, the slithering
> tracker takes only half the damage dealt to it, and the creature
> it is grappling takes the other half.

The feature doesn't say anything about the *source* of the damage or contain any exemption, therefore RAW it applies to **all** damage Slithering Tracker takes, including the damage originating from the grappled creature.

Additionally, let's have a look at the *Life Leech* Attack which imposes the Grapple on a failed save. It very clearly states what happens to the creature that the Tracker is grappling:

> (…) the target is restrained and unable to breathe unless it can breathe water. In addition, the grappled target takes 16 (3d10) necrotic damage (…)

Note that it isn't stated here either that being grappled somehow makes damage dealt by the creature exempt from the *Damage Transfer*, reinforcing the argument that it's not a thing.

Being in *Wild Shape* and biting is no different here than swinging a sword, this creature is an ooze, it's described as semi-liquid, I imagine being grappled by it is like being covered in a slime, it's impossible to hit/bite/attack in some other way without also hitting the creature underneath.